# chrome.storage is undefined for some users, but not most (and not me)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, storage, synchronization

I have an extension (tab wrangler - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/egnjhciaieeiiohknchakcodbpgjnchh).

I implemented chrome.storage.sync in the last version.  It works fine on my machine, but some users are reporting that they are getting "cannot find property 'sync' of undefined".  In otherwords, chrome.storage is undefined.

This is the github issue: https://github.com/jacobSingh/tabwrangler/issues/25

and here is the browser info of the two reporters:

- https://aboutmybrowser.com/3518315577
- https://aboutmybrowser.com/lQJKMjsO

Any advice would be appreciated.  Those are new versions and stock, so it seems like a chrome bug to me.

Comment: Maybe it's a new feature? Chrome is on v21 in the stable channel right now I think.